# Entity framework code first : Table per Hierarchy: Multiple collections of inherited type, how to map?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

There are 2 classes handshakes and byteArrays which are inherited from the base class OpcVariables

```
public class ByteArray : OpcVariable {}
public class Handshake : OpcVariable {}
public abstract partial class OpcVariable {}
```

The code first configuration to map the inherited types (VariableType = Discriminator).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OpcVariable>()
.Map<ByteArray>(m =>  m.Requires("VariableType").HasValue("ByteArray"))
.Map<Handshake>(m => m.Requires("VariableType").HasValue("Handshake"));
```

There is also a definition class containing 2 collections of the inherited types ByteArray and Handshake

```
partial class Definition : {
public virtual ICollection<ByteArray> ByteArrays { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Handshake> Handshakes { get; set; }
}
```

The code first (partial) configuration mapping to wire the collections

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Definition>()
.HasMany(e => e.Handshakes)
.WithRequired(e => e.Definition)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.DefinitionId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Definition>()
.HasMany(e => e.ByteArrays)
.WithRequired(e => e.Definition)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.DefinitionId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

To avoid an error I have removed the Foreign key and related object from the base class to aswell the ByteArray as the Handshake class:

```
public int DefinitionId { get; set; }
public virtual Definition Definition { get; set; }
```

I have already succesfully executed CRUD for the object Bytearray.
However when I try to get a definition with the query

```
var root = (Definition)(from x in Db.Definition.Include ("ByteArrays").Include("Handshakes").Include("PlcVariable") where x.Id == id select x).First();
```

I receive follow error

```
Invalid column name 'DefinitionId1'.
```

It seems that it is not possible to have two collections based upon 1 foreignkey. Apparently the FK DefinitionId becomes DefinitionId**1** (which doesn't exists in database), probably because the definitionId is defined in aswell handshake as bytearray.

Any suggestions to get the mappings right?

UPDATE  [Here I found a similar post](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/451117)

Comment: Your Here I found link is dead.